# Narrowing from int to short

Tags: java

I am working on *narrowing* and checked the following code :-

```
int i = 131072;
short s = (short)i;
System.out.println(s); //giving 0
```

This *narrowing* is outputting `0`. I am not able to get the logic behind.

Comment: And what exactly is your expected output? For me, the expected output is `0`.

Comment: Does this help? `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i))`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik not expecting anything, but just wanna know how this works

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3 - "A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T."

Comment: When in doubt, consult the spec...

Comment: @JonSkeet sure sir. Will do from now onwards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you cast a primitive to a smaller primitive the top bits are dropped.

Written another way you can see what is happening.

```
int i = 0x20000;
short s = (short) (i & 0xFFFF);
```

Note: the lower 16 bits of your integer are all zero, so the answer is 0.

As binary casting to (short) keeps only the lower 16 bits.

```
00000000 00000010 (00000000 00000000)
```

If you were to cast a longer number, it would still take the lower bits in each case.  Note: the `&` in each case is redundant and only to help clarity.

```
long l = 0x0FEDCBA987654321L;

// i = 0x87654321
int i = (int) (l & 0xFFFFFFFFL);

// c = \u4321
char c = (char) (l & 0xFFFF);

// s = 0x4321
short s = (short) (l & 0xFFFF);

// b = 0x21
byte b = (byte) (l & 0xFF);
```

Comment: This answer seems to explain the concepts behind the behavior in the most clear and thorough manner.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the behavior. Appreciated. Thanks:)

Comment: @AnkitNigam I have added examples for all the integer types.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sir i am not able to understand the hex representation of values like l & 0xff if you could throw some light please

Comment: @PeterLawrey also if you could explain why sometimes its giving negative values for some integer values

Comment: @AnkitNigam hexidecimal is a representation often used for binary data as it is shorter and easy to translate.  It consists of 16 possible digits 0 to 9 and A - F.  `F` in binary is `1111` so when you see `FF` it means 8 x 1's. and `FFFF` is 16 x 1's.  When you use `&` with a binary all the same bits have to be `1` for there to be a `1` result so when you `& 0xFF` you only retain the bits set ie the lower 8 bits.

Comment: @AnkitNigam Java uses signed `int`, `short` and `byte`.  It uses two-complement which means that if the top bit is `1`, the number is negative.  So you should expect a negative number whenever the top bit is 1.  This is true of `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`  Note: `char` is unsigned so the number is always non-negative.

Comment: @PeterLawrey very helpful. cleared a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

`131072` int is `00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000` in binary.

When you case it to `short`, only the lowest 16 bits remain - `00000000 00000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive values (`int`, `short`,...) are stored as binary values. `int` uses more bits than `short`. When you try to downcast you're cutting away bits which truncates (and potentially ruins) the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a down cast (which refers to objects), it's a narrowing cast, or truncation. When you perform such a cast, you just copy the two least significant bytes of the `int` to your `short`. If the integer if smaller than 2<sup>15</sup> you'd just ignore bytes containing zeroes, so it would just work.

This is not the case here, however. If you examine the binary representation of `131072` you'll see it's `100000000000000000`. So, the two least significant bytes are clearly `0`, which is exactly what you're getting.